# show SherlockDialogFragment on android 2.x

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am trying to show a `SherlockDialogFragment` called `PlayIt`

Code is as follow :

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
PlayIt p = new PlayIt();
p.show(fm, "play?");
```

But I am getting an error on show

Comment: Can you add the error you are getting to the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()` when using ActionbarSherlock.